# How can I use more than one speech to text function in the same web page? (ASP.NET, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have to give three speech enable button in the same web page. I can be able to give speech enable function to those three buttons, but the response is coming to the one text box only.

```html
 <span id='message' hidden></span>
   Month : <input type="text" name="monthStart" id="month">
   <button type="button" class="button-speaker"> </button>

   <span id='message' hidden></span>
   Month : <input type="text" name="monthEnd " id="month">
   <button type="button" class="button-speaker"> </button>
```

Comment: Please could you post some of your code so that we can see what you've tried so far, and can give some more specific help? Thanks :-)

Comment: Hard to know what the problem is without seeing the code and a more detailed description of the exact behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Adjust different id and send value on the base Textbox id.